Oksendal book unnecessary assumption
Consider Lemma 3.1.5 in Oksendal's book "Stochastic Differential Equations". He (unsurprisingly) doesn't bother defining what is meant by "\phi (t,\omega) is bounded"; futhermore, to make matters worse, it is unclear to me where in this proof the assumption of boundedness is used. If it is not used, he should mention this and why the assumption is assumed in the first place; if it is used, he should mention where and how.
Thanks.
It is a very concrete question : WHERE IS THE ASSUMPTION OF BOUNDEDNESS USED
Stop bullshitting me with "the question needs to be more focused", it can't be more focused and concrete than the way I asked it!


I think boundedness in this case just means boundedness as a function

Perhaps this is necessary to ensure well-definedness of the integrals?

The boundedness (as a function obviously) assumption may not be necessary but is obviously sufficient. I won't even bother to ask what should be wrong with this.

This is a calculus book. It does not really prove things. If you are looking for proof details, go check out some other textbooks.

@温泽海 you probably mean a stochastic calculus book. Even after seeing that screenshot you want to say that Oksendal did not really prove that lemma?

I mean that this book writes about stochastic calculus in a way a calculus book writes about analysis. If you read the book, you will know what I mean.

@KurtG. This makes no sense at all. It's not how mathematics is done. Your comment is, frankly, laughable (besides worthless).
